# Analytic function vanishes in an open unit disk. Show it vanishes identically.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

$f$ is an analytic function that vanishes in a unit disk which is a subset of domain $D$. Show that it vanishes all over $D$.

This was one of our quiz questions and I think we need to assume that $D$ is connected for it to be true. I couldn't find counterexample.

Comment: Probably a "domain" is defined to be an open and connected set.

Comment: That's what I was also wondering. I also think it should be open and connected.

Comment: If $D$ is an open set which has a connected component which is disjoint to the unit disk then you can simply define $f$ to be $1$ on that component and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: It's more generally true that if $z_n$ is a convergent sequence of points in $D$ whose limit is also in $D$, and if $f(z_n)$ is constant for all $n$, then $f$ is constant on $D$.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the domain $D$ as a disjoint union of two open sets:
$$U = \{z_0 \in D : f^{(k)}(z_0) = 0 \text{ for all } k\ge 0\}$$
and
$$V = \{z_0 \in D : f^{(k)}(z_0) \ne 0 \text{ for some } k\ge 0\}.$$
One of them is nonempty. Since $D$ is connected, the other must be empty.

The openness of $U$ is slightly subtle, hinging upon the fact that for any $z_0 \in D$, there is an open disk $B_r(z_0)$ with $r>0$ on which
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} (z-z_0)^k.$$

Comment: $V$ is open but why $U$ is open?

Comment: I wrote at the bottom of my answer that it’s subtle and gave a hint. Basically, if all derivatives vanish at $z_0$, then since analytic functions have power series representations at each point which are valid on an open set (given by the formula I gave), the function is identically zero in a neighborhood $W$ of $z_0$, and thus all derivatives of $f$ vanish at all points in $W$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a domain is open and arcwise connected. There is a theorem of Weierstass that says that if a function is analytic in a domain, and there is a sequence of points with at least one limit point in $D,$ take any sequence of distinct points in the disk converging to the center of the disk here, and $f$ takes value $0$ at each term of the sequence, which your sequence does since it vanishes on the entire disk, then $f$ is identically $0$ on the domain.

I always found this theorem pleasing. As a reference, you can find it in Hille, "Analytic Function Theory, Theorem 8.1.3 (I'm using the fourth printing of the first edition since I'm ancient. The text has been expropriated by Springer in its Graduate Texts series. In my index, the theorem is sourced under Zeros, frequency of.) I hope this helps.